# React filter data or show all result

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of books. it can filter by category.
How can I show all books if select "all" category.

```
books.filter(book => book.category.includes(currentcategory)).map(book =>
<div>
.
.
</div>
```

[Book Categories List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpr4s.png)

Comment: You can conditionally show the books.
if(currentCategory === 'all'){
  // show all books
} else {
  // show category books
}

Answer (score 3):

There's plenty of ways to do this, but here's one:

```js
(currentcategory === "all" 
   ? books
   : books.filter(book => book.category.includes(currentcategory))
).map(book => 
 <div>
.
.
</div>
)
```